Pyinstaller --noconsole makes the new console output disappear
I wrote a GUI by tkinter which allows user to click a button to execute another .exe file. The scripts looks like
# myapp.py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = tk.Button(self, text="execute", command=self._execute)
        button.pack()

    def _execute(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen(["run_something.exe", "the_arg"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
        p.communicate()

run_something.exe is created by pyinstaller, it would print some messages on terminal.
When I execute it on VSCode, everything is fine: a new console is pop up, and the messages is printed on the new console. Then I use pyinstaller to convert myapp.py into a .exe file by
pyinstaller --onedir --noconsole myapp.py

and the result is different. When I execute the myapp.exe, a new console is also pop up, but there is no messages be printed. I know run_something.exe is working because I can find out the output files generated by run_something.exe, only the messages are gone.
If --noconsole is removed, the new console can display the messages normally, but there is also another annoying console appears before the GUI. My question is how to avoid the messages in the new console created by subprocess.Popen(..., creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) disappears with the --noconsole flag?
